# What does "it may be offset, however, but the risks of the something" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was translating a technical text and came across the following part in bold format. I have two questions regarding this:

> Randomized trials have demonstrated that early ERCP (within 24 or 48 hours of admission) reduces complications, but not mortality, in patients with predicted severe gallstone-associated acute pancreatitis. The benefits of this invasive modality (release of the presumed impacted stone) may **be offset, however, but the risks of the procedure**, which include an increase in the severity of pancreatitis.

Q1: Is offset here a verb or noun? Does it mean "to neutralize some potential benefits"?

Q2: How should I get "however, but the risks of the procedure". It doesn't make any sense to me. I haven't seen any sentences like this before.

Comment: The "but" doesn't sound right.  Are you sure that's the correct quote?  As written the last sentence is incomplete.

Comment: @Andrew Yes I am 100 precent sure because I wrote it from the book in front of me. If you want I can send you a photo.

Comment: Ok then.  In that case there's a misprint somewhere because the sentence is not grammatical. If you change "but" to "by" does the sentence make sense to you?

Comment: @Andrew Yes, thanks now It's clear to me. However I am not sure if "offset " is a noun or the past participle. I would say it's the past participle.

Comment: It's the main verb of this sentence.  "The benefits (of Y) may be offset by X"  See [**to offset** (v)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/offset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sentence is not grammatically correct. Are you sure you copied it correctly? I think it should be this instead:

> The benefits of this invasive modality (release of the presumed impacted stone) may be offset, however, ***by*** the risks of the procedure, which include an increase in the severity of pancreatitis.

***May*** is a *modal auxiliary verb* (see here: http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/auxiliary_verbs.htm). ***Be offset*** is the main verb (passive form of ***to offset***).

The sentence is saying that the benefits might be cancelled out by the risks.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the answer. I just wrote exactly the words one by one from the hard copy. If you want I can send you the photo of the book.